# using Kotlin @Parcelize together with polymorphism

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-android-extensions

Hey I'm using one model as ***DTO, JsonCreator and Percelize***
my problem is that i want to use polymorphism (disassemble common part) and have no idea how to write it in ***Kotlin***.

```
@Parcelize
@Entity
open class Location (var lat: Double = 0.0, var lng: Double = 0.0) :Parcelable

@Parcelize
@Entity
class MapsMarker(lat: Double, lng: Double, var name: String): Location(lat, lng), Parcelable
```

An issue here is that compiles shouts

> Parcelizable constructor parameter should be "*var* or *val*"

for fields `lat`, `lng` of `MapsMarker`.

I'm using inheritance so I can't use val because I will override properties of the `Location` class. I also dont want my **room** @Entity will have duplicated fields.

If anyone knows the answer please help me ;)

Comment: Have you got the fix for your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

**@Parcelize** does not work well with inheritance [issue link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22139). You can still have custom parceler like mentioned [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html)

*<<<< not related to your question but consider giving a shot >>>>*

Your MapsMarker class is violating `is a` relationship -> MapsMarker is a Location?

It should not inherit from Location instead prefer composition -> MapsMarker `has a` Location

```
@Parcelize
@Entity
class MapsMarker(val location: Location, var name: String): Parcelable
```

You can find many blogs detailing class designs. [This](https://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/inheritance-composition-relationship.php) is the first related google result I got now.